# C program returns bad file descriptor on creating file with char * as filename

Tags: c

Basically, I want my code to open a file using a random filename. I expected the code to open the file properly yet, it returns a bad file descriptor even though I'm using a string name.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE* newFile;
    char* newFilename = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26];
    printf("The file is: %i\n", newFilename);

    //Access file
    int n = open(newFilename, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0777);
    newFile = fdopen(n, "wb");
    if(newFile == NULL) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    free(newFile);
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore the compiler warnings. `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26];` is a single char not a string. Please clarify what you expect/want the file names to be.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do when you print a pointer with `%i`. This is formally undefined behavior and all bets are off.

Comment: If you're not going to write executable code to the file, it should not be created with execute permissions.  Unless you want anyone to be able to clobber the file (rewrite its contents), you should not give the general public write permission on the file; you might want to be wary of other members of your group too.  Use `0644` or `0664` instead of `0777`.

Comment: If you're going to use `open()`, check the result — your call failed, so you got `EBADF` (bad file descriptor) when you tried to use it with `fdopen()`.  You should probably simply use `fopen()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I checked the result but it returned "bad file descriptor". I want to give it executable file permissions. I'm trying to get a single character string file name if you get what I mean. I don't understand how to generate a random single character but of type string because open requires char* type.

Comment: @RaymondChen I mean yes but I wanted to use it as a string and try to convert the ASCII to numeric form to see if there was something wrong with the type that I was inputting to open as newFilename.

Comment: The function you checked was `fdopen()`, not `open()`.  It was `fdopen()` that reported EBADF; `open()` isn't given a file descriptor so it never reports EBADF.  If you want a single-letter name (string), then you need an array of (at least) two characters (so that there is space for a null terminator), and you must ensure that there's a null byte after the first letter.  For example, `char name[] = { "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random() % 26], '\0' };` does the job.

Comment: @kaylum I didn't ignore them but I was trying to implicitly convert it to a string

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I kinda forgot about the null byte, I haven't really written C code in a while

Comment: I believe the basic problem is that you have to decide what you are trying to do? When you know type the topic on Google and you get answers enough to solve your issue. One basic rule is not inventing the wheel again, unless you do it to learn how your tools are working. If you need a temporary file name type that in Google and you find tmpnam() and the advantage is that the OS is handling the topic and not you. The people made the OS have thought about it far more than any of us. There are traps in using self made solutions because they can include bugs and problems not thought of by you.

Comment: Programming is to a large extent copying what others have done and implement it your way, pure theft is good programming (as long as it is on low level). Sometimes the theft is form yourself, your own reused library of functions. Especially C-programming is designed just to do that. C in it self is a bunch of very small parts and combined they are larger parts doing more specific and intelligent work. And in the end huge chunks of code do a lot of good work over and over again, a programming library.  If you do everything from scratch you have a huge load of work chasing bugs.

Answer (score 1):

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26]` is an integer (character code), not a pointer, so it doesn't suit for initializing `char*`.

You should create a separate buffer to store the character as a part of string.

In other words, you should use:

```c
    char newFilenameChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26];
    char newFilename[] = {newFilenameChar, '\0'};
    printf("The file is: %i\n", newFilenameChar);
```

instead of:

```c
    char* newFilename = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[random () % 26];
    printf("The file is: %i\n", newFilename);
```

Also note that passing something not allocated via `malloc()` family nor `NULL` to `free()` is bad. You should use `fclose()` to close files.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the free() thing. I kinda forgot about that when writing the proof of concept. My original code has it but not the POC

Answer (score 1):

Why is `newFilename` a `char *`? Indexing a string returns a `char`. If you want a random string, you'll need to allocate a string, iterate for how many characters you want, and set characters of that string to random values.

For example:

```c
/* We don't need a null terminator here. */
char alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char *str = calloc(CHAR_COUNT + 1, sizeof(char));
int i;

for (i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) {
  str[i] = alphabet[random() % 26];
}
```

Also note - not sure why you're opening a file with `fdopen` instead of `fopen` and closing it with `free` instead of `fclose`.

Comment: I used fdopen to edit the file permissions on the file.